# How to set the TextInputLayout hint with multiple styles?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I have a TextInputLayout and Edittext inside that, Need to make the hint with multiple styles like Date of Birth *mm/dd/yyyy*. The *mm/dd/yyyy* only should be italic and when we focus on the Edittext the same format text should be there on the top (as TextInputLayout working).

What I have tried, and the similar ones are out there:

1. Using SpannableString and setting the hint on EditText
2. Assigning the Htmlformatter and setting the hint on the editext

For both the above **Issue** -- when the focus is on the edittext the floating text not available.

3. Setting Hint on the TextInputLayout using SpannableString and Htmlformatter:
   For this one **Issue** The italics for mm/dd/yyyy wont work, but the focus and floating text works.

Need to know how we can style **TextInputLayout hint** with multiple styles having the floating also with the same styled text.

Comment: You want the textinputLayout to be non-italic when there is no-focus in edittext and the textinputLayout to be italic when there is focus on edittext?

Comment: Single text with multiple styles. eg: assume Date of Birth mm/dd/yyyy is the whole text, I want to have Date of Birth as normal text and dd/mm/yyy as italics. and it should work for both focus and on floating text.

Comment: Do you want the text in EditText to have different style than the hint text and the floating text?

Answer (score 0):

With the Material Components library, starting with [`1.2.0-alpha05`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/7822b6d05e7fe890a45fe688e3dbbaf2c76d618a) you can format the hint text.

Just use:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:hint="@string/hint_italic"
        >
```

with:

```
<string name="hint_italic">Date of Birth <i>mm/dd/yyyy</i></string>
```

[image][image]